# NODE_ENV=development node server.js is not working

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, settings, development-environment

NODE_ENV=development : The term 'NODE_ENV=development' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- NODE_ENV=development node server.js
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (NODE_ENV=development:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

I was trying to set env as development . A similar command with nodemon is used. As i do not have nodemon i wrote node, but it should work right?